# Dynamically creating a list of matching months in a MySQL where clause

Tags: mysql

I have a table which records versions of a data file by the date created (timestamp stored as an INT). 1 version is uploaded at most per month.

In the query below I am trying to get the import time for any version which was uploaded in Jan, Apr, Jul or Oct.

```
> SELECT import_time FROM importlog WHERE
> DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(import_time), '%m') = 1 OR
> REPEAT(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(import_time), '%m') = 1+3,3))
```

Currently this returns only Jan and Apr because I see the repeat is just doing the same condition 3 times.
What I believe needs to happen is for the 1+3 statement to be incemental each time the repeat statement occurs:

```
1+3;
1+6;
1+9;
```

I need a dynamic approach like this because although I have described it as January, in reality this date may also be variable based on the user.

My research hasn't been very fruitful as I keep coming back to auto_increment for creating INSERT queries. Any insight would be most welcome.

**Update**
I am able to do to this via a separate Mysql query that creates a string for all the months that are allowed.
$months = (1,4,7,10)
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(import_time), '%m') IN $months

So this is the quick and dirty solution, for my own learning I am wonder if a more sophisticated solution is possible.

Kind regards,
Carl

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do?

```
SELECT import_time
FROM importlog
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(import_time), '%m') in ('01', '04', '07', '10');
```

Comment: that would work fine if the months where static. However these could be dynamic, i.e. 2,5,8,11 depending on the user. Many thanks